# What is the difference beetween "You decided" and "You did decide"

Tags: past-tense, do-support, emphatic-polarity

I know that "You decided" is simple past, but I've never ever seen this kind of construction until I listened it in a song (You did decide):

> Pronoun + Simple Past(Past assistant did) + simple present

Then,
what is the difference? Does this construction really exit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple sentences, we don't *usually* use the verb *to do* to indicate the tense(past/present). It only occurs in a question(interrogative)

> ***did*** you decide it? -past
>
> ***do*** you decide it? -present

However, you can use it in simple sentence for *emphasis*

> *You decided it.* - simple past tense
>
> *You **did** decide it.* -simple past tense but more emphatic.

EDIT: It also occurs in negative sentences

> I **don't** decide it
>
> I **didn't** decide it

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche You are welcome. But I recommend you read this [Not so fast!](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) . If another user give you a more satisfying answer, feel free to unaccept mine :)

Comment: Ok it's true. I'll pay more attention in this detail! Thanks again!